# CSSの遠近効果付き3D回転をするとFirefoxで表示されなくなる

Tags: css, firefox

CSSのtransform:perspectiveを利用して要素に遠近法のような効果を与えるとき、ブラウザの画面幅によって要素が表示されなくなります。
(Firefoxで確認。Chrome/IEでは正常でした。)

サンプルコード:

```css
.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) perspective(300px) rotateX(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) perspective(300px) rotateX(45deg);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) perspective(300px) rotateX(45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) perspective(300px) rotateX(45deg);
  transform: translateX(-50%) perspective(300px) rotateX(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  この文章はダミーです。文字の大きさ、量、字間、行間等を確認するために入れています。この文章はダミーです。文字の大きさ、量、字間、行間等を確認するために入れています。この文章はダミーです。文字の大きさ、量、字間、行間等を確認するために入れています。この文章はダミーです。文字の大きさ、量、字間、行間等を確認するために入れています。この文章はダミーです。文字の大きさ、量、字間、行間等を確認するために入れています。この文章はダミーです。文字の大きさ、量、字間、行間等を確認するために入れています。この文章はダミーです。文字の大きさ、量、字間、行間等を確認するために入れています。この文章はダミーです。文字の大きさ、量、字間、行間等を確認するために入れています。この文章はダミーです。文字の大きさ、量、字間、行間等を確認するために入れています。この文章はダミーです。文字の大きさ、量、字間、行間等を確認するために入れています。この文章はダミーです。文字の大きさ、量、字間、行間等を確認するために入れています。この文章はダミーです。文字の大きさ、量、字間、行間等を確認するために入れています。この文章はダミーです。文字の大きさ、量、字間、行間等を確認するために入れています。この文章はダミーです。文字の大きさ、量、字間、行間等を確認するために入れています。この文章はダミーです。文字の大きさ、量、字間、行間等を確認するために入れています。この文章はダミーです。文字の大きさ、量、字間、行間等を確認するために入れています。この文章はダミーです。文字の大きさ、量、字間、行間等を確認するために入れています。この文章はダミーです。
</div>
```

サンプルコードをFirefoxで開き、Resultの横幅を縮めていくと表示されなくなります。

```
.text {
  transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(45deg);
}
```

何か指定のしかたが間違っているのでしょうか？
Firefoxでも表示できるようにする方法はありますか？

追記1: Firefoxのバージョンは34.0.5 (Windows)です。

追記2: サンプルではベンダプレフィックス`-moz-transform`を利用しています。(認識されていませんが)

Comment: 興味深いです。消える直前は `.text` のボックスの大きさが 12158x16242 なんですが、消えた時は 125669x173089 になってますね…

Comment: 問題解決の助けにはならないでしょうが、Firefoxは裏でテクスチャ作って3Dとして貼ってる予感がしますね。で、テクスチャの上限サイズにが16K(16384)ドットでアウトと… となると Mac や Linux での動作も知りたくなりますね。

Comment: Ubuntu の Firefox で試して、同様の症状が再現することを確認できました。

Comment: 要素を調査でCSSのtransformをみると、見えなくなったタイミングで図形がひっくり返っていますね。裏側だからレンダリングされていないのかも・・・。なお、leftとtranslateXをなくせば表示はされます（意図する距離感ではないのだと思いますが）。

Comment: 知らなかったのですが、`left:50%`を指定すると自動的に`width:50%`扱いになるように見えますね。
leftを無くせばwidthが広がる→テクスチャのサイズが小さくなる→表示される、ということでしょうか。やはりサイズなのか...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

レイアウトは指定前と比べて 1px もズレないのでこれで良いかもしれない。`flat` 指定だと消えます。(On FF24.8, FF33.1, FF34.05 - Win7)

消える直前モニタに突き刺さったような状態になってて面白い。なんででしょうね。

Comment: おお、消えなくなりました！（http://jsfiddle.net/r1onp8j3/2/）
ただ、この指定で何で消えなくなるのかが良くわからないですね。
でもきちんと動作します。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

> -moz-transform: rotateX(45deg);

Firefoxの場合、上記でどうでしょう？

Comment: すみません。書き忘れていました。
サンプルソースでは一応`-moz-transform`を使っています。

ただ、`-moz-transform`は認識されていないので、もう今のFirefoxでは`transform`が標準になっているようです。